# How to Calculate only distinct values in rdlc report

Tags: visual-studio, rdlc

Hey I want to sum only distinct values in rdlc report but I was failed every time. Give some good tips to complete this task.

I have a rdlc report and Values return like this

```
Given Wt    Retained    Given%  Discount    Net Payment
23.86       10.225       70      1406        68911
6.007       2.575        70      177         17528
23.86       10.225       70      1406        68911
6.007       2.575        70      177         17528
```

I want to sum only distinct value that is `23.86+6.007=29.867` but I got when I use `=SUM(Cdec(Fields!Given_wt.Value))` i.e `59.734`

Please give some useful tips

Comment: what is the reasoning behind this approach? it seems flawed, what if two weights are the same by chance, but belong to different bookings? you'll need a key or a set of keys, and "distinctize" earlier, in the primary resultset of the underlying query/view/whatever your source is.

Comment: GL AC48 A36 20 0.1 0.5 19.400 34.085 54581.06 23.86 10.225 70 1406 68911 100452.68 NECKALCE
GL AC52 A36 2 0.1 0.1 1.800 8.582 3858 6.007 2.575 70 177 17528 25292.4 RUBY/EMRALD
GL AC48 A36 22.01 0.5 0.11 21.400 34.085 45871.62 23.86 10.225 70 1406 68911 100452.68 STUD
GL AC52 A36 10 0.6 1.4 8.000 8.582 21434.4 6.007 2.575 70 177 17528 25292.4 LOCKET

Comment: so include it in your question. and specify which SQL dialect it is, mysql, mssql, access, ... answers may differ, for example Access has the DISTINCTROW predicate, which MSSQL lacks

Comment: err no I meant the source code of the query, not the raw data. and use the "edit" link to add information to the question.